# Can we directly write Python code under "run | " section in action.yml file

Tags: python, github-actions, building-github-actions

In GitHub Actions, can we directly write python code under `run |` -section in `action.yml` file?
Can I write GitHub Actions scripts in Python?

Answer (score 19):

There is a [built-in `shell` keyword](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-a-specific-shell) for python.

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Display the path
    run: |
      import os
      print(os.environ['PATH'])
    shell: python
```

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-running-an-inline-python-script

---

You can also use a [custom shell](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#custom-shell). GitHub Actions writes the value of `run` to a temporary file and passes it to the specified shell by replacing `{0}` with the file name of the temporary script.

```yaml
steps:
  - name: Display the path
    run: |
      import os
      print(os.environ['PATH'])
    shell: python {0}
```